# Are bounty posters notified they are in the grace period?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty, notifications

An OP set a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30613894/how-can-i-convert-this-php-code-in-a-way-that-will-allow-me-to-add-it-in-js-usi/30796371), which in now in the grace period, but he hasn't been active for the last 3 days. Are emails sent to these people reminding them to come back?

Comment: There is a `##Reminder: Your Bounty Ended!` notification mail.

Comment: Apparently there are even user settings for automated mails: [Please stop sending me emails when my bounty is going to expire soon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180524), so they might just be disabled.

Comment: I've never set a bounty (yet) so I appreciate the insight.

Comment: He might think it gets awarded automatically, or he got his answer and has gone on walkabout.  Since you posted that answer after the bounty was offered and it has >2 upvotes, you will automatically get half.

Comment: @Plutonix That could very well be true. Though, this situation has occurred many times before with half the bounty being awarded, enough so that I wanted to find out if they are notified.

Comment: If you look at his history, this is not the first time - each one I click thru shows an award of half what was offered.  What a waste of rep!

Comment: Yes there is some notification

Comment: Thanks everyone! I wanted to know if there are emails sent. You say there are unless explicitly disabled, so you answered my question.